# Possible values for R resources

Tags: android

I am using the R.drawable.x values as keys in a hashmap, but I need a value that means the absence of a drawable. For this I need to know what the possible values for R resources are. Does anybody know this or is it defined somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordind to the [Ressources documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) there is a method [getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the int value of a ressource and they precise :

> Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource
>   ID.)

So 0 seem to work.

Hope this helps.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Regex for drawable names:`[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_]*`